# Trying to create a simple sum calculator

Tags: javascript

Trying to create a simple calculator in javascript with no jquery with one input that expects comma-separated numbers to find the sum and the average.

This is my js

```
function getSum() {
  var Sum = document.getElementById('numb').value;

}

function sum() {
  var sumOfNumb = 0, numb = document.getElementById("numb").value.split(",");

  for (var i = 0; i < numb.length; i++) {
      sumOfNumb += parseInt(numb[i]);
  }

  document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sumOfNumb;
}
```

Relevant markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head lang="en"> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title></title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <input id="numb" type="number" /> 
    <input type='button' value="button" onclick='Sum()' /> 
    <script src="js/main.js"></script> 
</body>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Can you post your code or your attempt at the code?

Comment: try `a=[1,2,3,4,5,6/* numbers here */],b=0,l=a.length;for(i=0;i<l;i++){b+=a[i]}console.log("Sum :"+b),console.log("Av :"+(b/l));`

Comment: Your bottom function works...  Just assign it to an event listener and delete `getSum()` as you're not doing anything with it

Comment: Can we seeing the matching HTML?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<input id="numb" type="number" />




<input type='button' value="button" onclick='Sum()' />

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can't have a comma separated list of numbers in a `number` type `input` (at least in modern browsers), it has to be `type="text`

2) Your `onclick="Sum()"` is using a capitalized `S`, it should be `onclick="sum()"`

3) You have no `div` with the ID `sum`, so your output never shows.

New markup:

```
<input id="numb" type="text" /> 
<input type='button' value="button" onclick='sum()' /> 
<div id="sum"></div>
```

Comment: alright my js is still wrong though. what is the problem                                             
`document.addEventListener("click", numb);


function numb() {
    var sumOfNumb = 0, numb = document.getElementById("numb").value.split(",");

    for (var i = 0; i < numb.length; i++) {
        sumOfNumb += parseInt(numb[i]);
    }

    document.getElementById("numb").innerHTML = sumOfNumb;
}`

Comment: You've changed a lot there... it worked before just by fixing what I said.  Now there's other issues.  1) you added the event listener to `document` instead of the button, 2) you're setting the `innerHTML` of an `input` (not just a `div` anymore -- in that case, you should be setting the value.